# how to run a thread in background to read data from database all time when app is not open

Tags: android, multithreading

I am making a reminder app in which i have created a database. I want that a thread should run in background all the time so that when the required time of reminder comes , it should beef an alarm or show a notification . I am new in android . So please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) to perform network related tasks in background. You can use both **periodic** and **one time** tasks using this API. This serves exactly what you need

Comment: thanks. If u have any code example related to it, please give me.

Comment: I am on phone right now, can update code in an hour.

Comment: There are already examples of how to use GCM Network Manager in the link provided in the answer. Anyway you can follow this example too: http://jacktech24.logdown.com/posts/292141-working-with-gcmnetworkmanager-on

Answer (score 0):

You can use android AlarmManager to execute a background Service and certain intervals

Comment: Thanks. I am new in android so please give some example on this.